# Preorder, inorder, postorder for tree in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, tree

Please review my code for preorder, inorder and postorder of a tree. I am using C++11 (or wanted to use), so let me know if anything is deviating from the C++11 standard.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::shared_ptr;

struct node
{
    int data;
    shared_ptr<node> left;
    shared_ptr<node> right;
};

shared_ptr<node> newNode (int i)
{
    shared_ptr<node> n (new node);
    n->data = i;
    n->left = nullptr;
    n->right = nullptr;

    return n;
}

void preOrder(shared_ptr<node> n)
{
    if(n == nullptr)
        return;

    cout<<n->data<<" ";

    preOrder((n->left));
    preOrder((n->right));
}

void inOrder(shared_ptr<node> n)
{
    if(n == nullptr)
        return;

    inOrder((n->left));

    cout<<n->data<<" ";

    inOrder((n->right));
}

void postOrder(shared_ptr<node> n)
{
    if(n == nullptr)
        return;

    postOrder((n->left));
    postOrder((n->right));

    cout<<n->data<<" ";

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    shared_ptr<node> r = newNode(1); 
     (r->left) = newNode(2);
     (r->right) = newNode(3);
    (r->left->left) = newNode(4);
    (r->left->right) = newNode(5);

    preOrder(r);
    cout<<endl;

    inOrder(r);
    cout<<endl;

    postOrder(r);
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Memory management

Don't think that is the appropriate smart pointer.

```
shared_ptr<node> newNode (int i)
```

Do you have plans to actually share ownership of a node? Or is it more likely that ownership will be done by the patent of the node? I would have gone with `unique_ptr<node>` if I was going to use smart pointers.

#### make_X

You should not be using `new` with smart pointers. There are `make_XXX` commands that combine all the memory allocation required into a single operation (thus making it more efficient).

```
   std::shared_ptr<node> n  = std::make_shared<node>(val);  // or make_unique
```

#### Using

I suppose this is better than `using namespace std;`

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::shared_ptr;
```

But its still pretty sloppy and lazy. Pull those declarations into the tightest scope possible (ie inside a function).

#### Braces

This looks strange

```
preOrder((n->left));
preOrder((n->right));
```

Now I am all for using braces to make expression easy to read or to force a particular evaluation order. But this just looks strange and does not help in the evaluation.

#### Prefer '\n'

Prefer '\n' to std::endl.

The difference between the two is that `std::endl` forces a flush after placing the new line on the stream. It is very rare that you actually want to force a flush (as the runtime is much better at making that decision than you). Excessive flushing just makes the stream libraries slow.

- [“\n” or '\n' or std::endl to std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8311058/14065)
- [Why does endl get used as a synonym for “\n” even though it incurs significant performance penalties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2122986/14065)

Comment: I have to disagree with your last comment about newlines: when a stream is being used for something resembling human-readable output, one should flush generously. Especially on newline, since one usually *wants* line buffering, unless they're writing multiple at once (but still want a flush after the last line). I've seen lots of deep confusion with programs written in other languages when someone decides to redirect output to a file and the runtime decides that `STDOUT` should be fully buffered rather than line buffered.

Comment: @Hurkyl: You have a misconception of how buffering works. Before input is read from the standard input the standard output is automatically flushed. So you always know the question. So my advice still holds.

Comment: It's an optimization, and usually a *premature* optimization. I wasn't even thinking about prompting for input, but things like printing diagnostic information or progress reports or printing results as they're produced or anything else that a person might like to see as output from a program.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Diagnostic information should be on std::err (which is not buffered and thus does not need to be flushed). The only thing that will happen when you flush is that you slow the output down dramatically. If your output is already slow then maybe a manual flush could be useful to show progress (but those are by far the exception not the rule). So again my advice stands.

Comment: @Hurkyl: PS this has been discussed at length on stack overflow. You should do a search and some reading. http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/14065

Comment: `It's an optimization, and usually a premature optimization`: I look at the other way. `std::endl` is the premature optimization. The `'\n'` is the normal way of doing it (you are adding a newline). Flushing is the optimizaation you are trying to add (and usually backfires).

Comment: You are literally advising people to introduce complication into the usage of their programs (adding a delay between when the program writes output and when it is actually visible to the user) in order to improve I/O performance without even considering whether or not I/O is a bottleneck for their program. I am flabbergasted that you manage to construe the opposite advice as being the premature optimization rather than your own.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I am not saying don't use `std::endl`. I am saying think about when you use it. I don't see how this adds any complexity. Nor do I see it introducing a delay (as the flushing is happening automatically when required). You are just trying to prematurely optimize the flush when you think it is a good idea, rather than allow the runtime to do it when **it knows** it is a good time. Feel free to apply the downvote. But please take the time and read what the experts are saying on SO.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Can you show me how this advice damages the code above or does it improve it? Since the whole use is put a line between each block it improves the application as it makes the intention more explicit (the OP want a new line not a flush).

Comment: I read your link. It refutes your position. The top answer offers a great reason to flush output; in fact, one of the ones I am giving. The second answer says to use `\n` *when you're worried about performance*, not as your default choice. And it also suggests one of the habits I describe above (use `\n` in the middle of one block of output, but explicitly flush when its all written).

Comment: For this program in isolation? It doesn't matter whether you use `\n` or `std::endl`; the results will be indistinguishable in any environment I can conceive at the moment. My problem is with your suggestion of habits to adopt; adopting a habit that will lead you to avoid flushing when output should be made visible will do more harm than adopting a habit that might lead you to write slow I/O code in a circumstance where the performance matters.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Both the top two answers say what I say (since the second one is mine I tend to know). What I am trying to promote is not to unthinking use of `std::endl`. Using `'\n'` will never cause an issue. It will show the output in a timely fashion thus a good habit. Using `std::endl` indiscriminately is going to cause problems (problems is to strong). You should only use it when you explicitly mean flush (not just as a new line). Thus it is a bad habit. So my suggestion never a problem. std::endl sometimes a problem. Best advice prefer `'\n'`

Comment: I can say from experience that you are flat out wrong that using `'\n'` will never cause an issue. I have seen many occurrences of people wasting days on debugging efforts because people relied on the runtime using line-buffering, and then not understand what was going on when they redirected output to a file and the runtime decides that `stdout` should now be fully buffered. Similarly I have seen week-long runs on clusters aborted because IO buffers never got flushed. The few times where a program ran slow because of too much flushing? Quickly detected and easily fixed.

Comment: OK. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8311058/14065

Comment: @Hurkyl: Well I can say by experience that you are flat out wrong as well. I can come up with arguments that do the exact reverse. As I have said this has been discussed many times on SO. You are in the minority (by a long shot). I suggest more reading on the topic on SO. Argue with the experts there. Maybe ask the question which is best start a real discussion that can be tracked.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<node> n  = std::make_shared<int>(val);` Huh? The types seems not to match.

Comment: @dyp: I wish you could pile on some more rep here so you could repair that kind of stupid type. Thanks :-)

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye Even if, it's not obvious to me how to fix the issue if `val` is an `int`: The `node` struct has no (user-declared) constructors, and `make_shared` doesn't use uniform initialization.

Answer (score 8):

One major problem with this approach (without a class) is that adding new nodes is very tedious.  If you were to give this code to another user, *but* with an empty driver, they would have a hard time figuring out how to get this to work.  Even if they do figure it out, it appears that each line will get longer as more and more nodes are inserted.

If you had a class with a root node and interface functions, it would be *much* easier to do this, both for you and for others.  The user would not need to create a root, and you can design the interface to allow similar functionality from `main()`.  This is also important because, ideally, node data structures are supposed to stay hidden from the user within the implementation.  If you're concerned with the user not knowing how each of the nodes are situated, you can also display them in a tree-like manner instead or alongside this current display.  This would avoid the need to read the manual insertion code and instead look at the console output.

You can even use templates to allow any other data type and not just `int` values.  That would make your program look more like C++11, too.  As for the interface, you can also allow certain nodes, or all of the nodes, to be deleted.

Beyond all that, this code looks pretty clean (minus the little inconsistent indentation in `main()`).  But usability-wise, it's very weak.  There are *a lot* of resources around for trees, and you can even find them on this site.  You should see that they utilize a class as I've described.  You can still keep all of this code for this class.  It just needs to be put into the member functions and called with a new class instance.

Answer (score 5):

Except for educational purposes, one shouldn't re-implement data structures provided by the standard library. The standard template library (STL) provides many generic [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). The STL also provides the <[`algorithm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)> header, which contains generic algorithms that operate on the STL containers.

Your code focuses on the algorithmic machinations of tree data structure, this is fine for a learning exercise, but you want to work at a higher abstraction level than this, you want to be able to focus on making your code useful. Re-inventing the wheel is something you should avoid, again except for a learning exercise; it is very instructive to build standard data structures from scratch.

When learning how trees work, it doesn't matter if you manipulate the tree directly instead of creating and using member functions to maintain the tree. You did however specifically ask about C++11; your code is closer to C than C++. You certainly used features of C++11 (smart pointers and nullptr), but it is still basically C code. Improvements to align your code with the spirit of C++11:

- Your tree should be a class, it should maintain the tree and hide the implementation
- The node class probably should be an nested class within your tree
- Your tree class should be templated; don't hardcode the type!
- Your traversals should be implemented with the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Also there are some algorithmic improvements you could make, e.x. balancing your tree so that it doesn't become lopsided or degrade into a linked list.

If this is just a learning exercise, the code is fine for "C" code. If you intend to do anything useful with this code it definitely need improvement. Without knowing what you intend to do it is hard to make a suggestion on what data structure to use. The STL provides many structures for different purposes.

If you need a list, you can use `<vector>` or `<list>`
If you just need a collection of objects use a '<'set'>' (backed by a balanced tree) 
If you need a key-value pair mapping use `<map>`
If you need a queue use a `<queue>`

All of these data structures can be operated on by the  header, for example:

```
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int i){cout << i;});
```

would print all the items in the set assuming s is a `set<int>`; the third argument is a lambda expression, it defines a function that `for_each` will call on each member of the set.